# Работа WebSocket в корпоративных сетях

Tags: node.js, websocket

Есть сервер на WebSocket (node.JS), всё отлично работает.
Единственный момент - если человек заходит на сайт "с рабочего компьютера" и пытается подключиться к WebSocket серверу - сервер отваливается.
Отваливается так же и при попытке подключиться через ssl (сертификат не самоподписанный). Обычный пользователь подключается свободно, все же кто "с работы" - не могут.

Я понимаю что корпоративные прокси в большинстве случаев так заточены, отрубать всё что им не знакомо.
Вопрос: есть ли возможность обойти такие запреты (настройка nginx/подключение специальных модулей, если есть) что бы при попытке подключения с корпоративных сетей, рукопожатие проходило без проблем?
В какую сторону копать?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обойти почти любой прокси можно используя https (в случае веб-сокетов - wss). В зашифрованный трафик могут вмешаться только те прокси-серверы, которые используют подмену сертификата. Но если админ сумел настроить такой прокси - то и для веб-сокетов у него вполне может хватить квалификации.

Решение же, работающее в общем случае - автоматический fallback на long pooling в случае недоступности веб-сокетов.

Comment: Как уже говорилось: используется как раз https/wss, тем не менее несколько человек всё равно жалуются - с работы зайти не могут.
Вероятно всё таки придётся прибегать к вариантам типа socket.io, хоть и не хотелось.
Спасибо Вам:)